# Store / Market location on application install - refferer

Tags: android, google-play, referrer

I checked some threads similar to my question but didn't manage to find complete answer to my inquiry.

Is it possible in android application (without using google analytics for android) to catch referer - market from which user downloaded / installed app.

For example i publish application in
a. google / play store
b. amazon store
c. getjar

Now I would need in code to get info from which store its downloaded / installed in url or any other form.

This is needed to make some small differences in app - for different stores. For example 
display different more apps link, since we don't have same apps on all stores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getInstallerPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) to check who installed the app. That obviously only works after the app is actually installed, and you'll have to find the packages by experimentation.

Generally it is a better idea to create different build for different stores using resource flags, etc.